# Sending Mail using dynamic values with asp.net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net, email, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm sending email via asp.net Core 2.0 like this [tutorial](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/08/20/sending-email-net-core-2-0/), so I have something like this into my controller

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mysmtpserver");
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("whoever@me.com");
mailMessage.To.Add("receiver@me.com");
mailMessage.Body = "body";
mailMessage.Subject = "subject";
client.Send(mailMessage);
```

and it works, but I want to do it less generic. Like sending code to class and call it from controller. For example in class I want to use variables instead static content like

```
mailMessage.Body = "body";
```

Instead this I want to use something like:

```
 var body;
 mailMessage.Body = body;
```

So into controller have ability to change that content. How can I achieve that? Regards

Comment: So you have the code to send email... And you want the code to write a controller and model to send email? That's a little ambiguous especially without any existing MVC for where you are stuck...'

Comment: I have working send email code... I just want to do it less generic and change data when I want. For example in home controller I want to call my mail method from class. So I want to override `mailMessage.Body` for this message. Now In products controller I want to use same class, but I want to override `mailMessage.Body` for this controller method too... So in conclusion I want to have one method into class and change content in controller when I want@AustinFrench

Comment: Why don't you simply make a function SendEmail and pass the resulting variable from the controller as a parameter to the function?

Comment: can you explain me how can achieve that? @progrAmmar

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, add a private function called `SendEmail` something like

```
private bool SendEmail(string mail_to, string mail_subject, mail_body)
{
   bool result = false;
   try
   {
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mysmtpserver");
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
    mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("whoever@me.com");
    mailMessage.To.Add(mail_to);
    mailMessage.Body = mail_body;
    mailMessage.Subject = mail_subject;
    client.Send(mailMessage);
    result = true;
   }
   catch(Exception ex){ result = false; }
   return result;
}
```

Use it in your controller

```
string mailBody = "Anything can be in the body\n. Mail contents.";
string subject = "Mail Subject";
string mailTo = "someone@someone.com"
SendEmail(mailTo, subject, mailBody)
```